# Maintaining Object state in javascript DOJO

Tags: javascript, html, events, dojo, dom-events

I have the following code to call an function on each button in a page.

```
       dojo.query('.btn').forEach(function(item){
        Obj =   new MyClass(item); // class calls the ajax request on error of each btn click I have to handle some functionality in below function showError
        dojo.connect(Obj, 'showError', dojo.hitch(Obj, function(errors){
            console.log(Obj + 'came');
        }));
```

Here I tried using dojo.hitch to maintain state of each object Obj, But it is not maintaining.Only first Obj is firing.For second Button also, the first Obj is firing.Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: Have you checked if your forEachLoop submits the correct items? That it loops through the hole bunch of Buttons you made or does it break at the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Obj` is declared as a global variable. Try putting a `var` in front of it. For example:

```
var Obj = new MyClass(item);
```

If you don't provide the `var`, it will create a globally accessible variable called `Obj`. This means that each time you loop, you refer to the same global variable. The result of this is that each one is connected to the same `Obj` (and that's why both buttons are connected to the same object).

Also, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) on StackOverflow to get a more detailed view about declaring variables and the global scope.